# Using maven-bundle-plugin with the maven-shade-plugin

Tags: maven, osgi, maven-shade-plugin, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm using the maven-shade-plugin to relocate some packages during the package phase of my build. I'm also using the maven-bundle-plugin to generate a manifest. The problem is the bundle plugin runs before the shade plugin (during the process-classes phase), and doesn't include any of my shaded packages in the generated manifest's exports.

How can I get these two plugins to play nice with each other, so that my relocated packages are treated like any other package by the bundle plugin?

--

By request, the Shade and bundle sections of my POM:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <artifact>cglib:cglib</artifact>
          <includes>
            <include>net/sf/cglib/core/**</include>
            <include>net/sf/cglib/proxy/**</include>
          </includes>
        </filter>
      </filters>
      <relocations>
        <relocation>
          <pattern>net.sf.cglib</pattern>
          <shadedPattern>org.modelmapper.internal.cglib</shadedPattern>
        </relocation>
        <relocation>
          <pattern>org.objectweb.asm</pattern>
          <shadedPattern>org.modelmapper.internal.asm</shadedPattern>
        </relocation>
      </relocations>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>manifest</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Export-Package>
          org.modelmapper,
          org.modelmapper.builder,
          org.modelmapper.config,
          org.modelmapper.convention,
          org.modelmapper.spi
        </Export-Package>
        <Private-Package>
          org.modelmapper.internal.**
        </Private-Package>
        <Import-Package>
          *
        </Import-Package>
        <Include-Resource>
          {maven-resources},
          {maven-dependencies}
        </Include-Resource>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Taken [from here](https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper/blob/master/core/pom.xml)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your pom.xml, including `<Export-Package>` and `<relocations>` sections.

Comment: Is this related to osgi and/or fuse ESB? worth adding those tags?

Comment: @vikingsteve - yes, OSGI. Which tags do you mean?

Comment: If you remove the executions binded to _process-classes_ and _package_, then run `mvn compile shade:shade bundle:manifest package` from the command line, is the manifest generated correctly?

Comment: Also, are you using maven 3.0.3 or up?

Comment: @Jonathan i meant to suggest adding the osgi tag to your question, which looks like has been done :)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Removing the executions from the plugins results in something like `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default-cli) on project modelmapper: Failed to create shaded artifact, project main artifact does not exist.`... depending on what goals I execute. And yes, I'm using mvn 3.0.3.

Comment: Weird, what is your packaging type? JAR (`<packaging>jar</packaging>`) or Bundle? Try binding both plugins to `package` phase (making sure that maven bundle appears after maven shade in your plugin list). Does it package the bundle correctly and add the desired metadata?

Comment: Packaging is jar. Setting both plugins to run in package phase: `Error assembling JAR: Manifest file: /Users/jonathan/dev/modelmapper/core/target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF does not exist.` [Full POM](https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper/blob/master/core/pom.xml)

Comment: It would be great if you could accept or post an answer to this question. It's been viewed over 4k times since 2013.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to dump maven bundle plugin altogether and use Maven Shade Plugin [ManifestResourceTransformer](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ManifestResourceTransformer) to add the desired OSGI metadata to the manifest.

Take a look at [xbean-asm-shaded/pom.xml](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/geronimo/xbean/trunk/xbean-asm-shaded/pom.xml) for a example.

```
<transformers>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
    <manifestEntries>
      <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
      <Export-Package>
        org.apache.xbean.asm;org.modelmapper.builder; ...
      </Export-Package>
      <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
      <Private-Package>org.modelmapper.internal ...</Private-Package>
   </manifestEntries>
</transformer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is very simple. You still can use maven-bundle-plugin and maven-shade-plugin at the same time. You just need to remember about the order. If you use bundle packaging maven bundle plugin will get executed during package phase before maven-shade. But that's not so wrong.

Here is the deal.

- Use Private-Package: pkg.name.before.shading
- Make maven-shade-plugin with one <include>null:null</include> - this will prevent shade plugin from creating empty jar
- use maven-shade-plugin relocations - from pkg.name.before.shading to other.pkg.

You may see this trick working in FasterXML [jackson-module-paranamer](https://github.com/splatch/jackson-module-paranamer/blob/ee2022fc7e17ed048dad18dfaa34194192e1adc3/pom.xml)

Comment: This works perfectly except when you want to export the shaded packages themselves.  The solution proposed here will only include packages from src/main/java.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that after the `compile` phase is done you want to:

1. relocate some classes with the shade plugin
2. create a manifest with the bundle plugin
3. pack it all up with the jar plugin

> The problem is the bundle plugin runs before the shade plugin

The bundle plugin is binded to `process-classes` phase which comes [before](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) the `package` phase to which the shade plugin is bound.

I suggest that you bind the shade plugin to `process-classes` phase also. Change shade plugin configuration like this:

```
<phase>process-classes</phase>
```

Since the shade plugin definition comes before the bundle plugin definition in the pom file, the shade plugin will run before the bundle plugin during the `process-classes` phase.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It fails with something like this `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default) on project modelmapper: Failed to create shaded artifact, project main artifact does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat `transformer` implementing just this functionality from Hazelcast - [HazelcastManifestTransformer (ver 3.9)](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/javadoc/com/hazelcast/buildutils/HazelcastManifestTransformer.html). What it does is thoughtfully merging the `Import-Package` and `Export-Package` attributes, enabling the user to exclude extend/reduce the default merged result.

How to use it in your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
      <artifactId>hazelcast-build-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="com.hazelcast.buildutils.HazelcastManifestTransformer">
            <mainClass>...</mainClass>
            <!-- the tag below is required due to a missing null-check it seems -->
            <overrideInstructions></overrideInstructions>
      </configuration>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The override instructions (`Export/Import-Package`) are comma delimited package names, preceded with an exclamation mark whenever we want to exclude those specific ones from the list.

Hope this helps! I do realize that's an old question, but seems the Hazelcast's transformer isn't gaining much publicity.